# How to make two-coloured stripe using CSS?

Tags: html, css, colors

I want to make the following stripe. What is the right way of doing that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a short `div` with darker color inside another with lighter color.

That's how Bootstrap implement its progress bar.

HTML:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
    <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.progress {
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are looking for gradients. This is typically used when you want to style with multiple colors.

Gradients are displayed by default vertically. To display it horizontally, we need to use the optional `direction` parameter. In this case, it is `to right`.

I can't make out what the colors used in the image are, but they look like darkgreen and lime.

```css
#colored {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, DarkGreen 70%, lime);
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="colored"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternately, you can use a gradient:

```js
var progress = document.getElementById('progress');
var complete = 0;
var c1 = '#75ae2c', c2 = '#9dd156';
var timer = setTimeout(function loop() {
  var bg = 'linear-gradient(to right, ' + c1 + ' 0%,' + c1 + ' ' + complete + '%,' + c2 + ' ' + complete + '%,' + c2 + ' 100%)';
  progress.style.background = bg;
  progress.innerHTML = 'Process is ' + complete + '% complete';

  complete++;
  if (complete <= 100) setTimeout(loop, 100);
}, 0);
```

```css
#progress {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="progress">
</div>
```

It is a tiny bit more complex, but the advantage over div-inside-div is that it doesn't interfere with the content.

Answer (score 0):

Have a `div` with 2 `div`'s inside

HTML:

```
<div class="stripe">
    <div class="stripe-left"></div>
    <div class="stripe-right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.stripe {
    height: 20px;
    width: 200px;
}

.stripe-left {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: red;
}

.stripe-right {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```